# Find the standard matrix of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let
$M:\mathbb{R}^2\ \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear transformation that first reflects it through the line $x_1=x_{2}$, and then rotates each point counterclockwise around the origin by
$\frac{5 \pi}{4}$ radians.

Find the standard matrix of $M$

So I was thinking, since it's the line $x_1 = x_2$, looking at it graphically, I would have

$$\begin{pmatrix}
cos(x)&-sin(x)\\
sin(x)&cos(x)\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
which then becomes

$$\begin{pmatrix}
sin(x)&cos(x)\\
cos(x)&-sin(x)\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

which then becomes (using $x = \frac{5\pi}{4}$)
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

But that's the wrong answer. Would really appreciate some help with these, I don't fully understand how to algebraically find / convert these reflections yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reflection through the line $x_1=x_2$ maps $\left(1,1\right)$ into itself and it maps $\left(-1,1\right)$ into $\left(1,-1\right)$. So, its matrix with respect to the standard basis is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. And the matrix of a counterclockwise rotation around the origin with angle $\frac{5\pi}4$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}-\frac1{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt2}\\-\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}.$$So, take$$\begin{bmatrix}-\frac1{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt2}\\-\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\frac1{\sqrt2}\\-\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Why is the first row, second column the one that is positive rather than second row second column? We are first supposed to reflect, correct? If so, $-sin(x)$ will be in the second row second column I believe?

Comment: Because it's the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}4\right)&-\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}4\right)\\\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}4\right)&\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}4\right)\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Yeah, but you're reflecting it first right? So shouldn't it be $-\sin(x)$ at the second row, second column?

Comment: No, I am **not** reflecting first. The matrix that I wrote is the matrix of a counterclockwise rotation around the origin with angle $\frac{5\pi}4$. **After** having computed that matrix, I multiply it by the matrix corresponding to the reflection.

Comment: Hey Jose, it's me again. I have a quick additional question to this. Let's call matrix $A$ the matrix we want to transform using a reflection, and the reflection being $R$. Why is it that in your example, it works perfectly fine doing $A \times R$ yet, in my other question from the other day, I need to multiply it like $R \times A$ (apparently order is important for matrix multiplication)? See my other question I'm referring to if you have a minute: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158927/linear-transformations-and-reflections (the answer by mathcounterexample)

Comment: In this problem, it is stated that the *first* transformation is the reflection. In that other problem, the reflection is the *second* transformation.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I hope this was it, but I will probably think of a few more questions :P

Comment: I just tried another one for practice, and I keep getting it twisted with the concept of first and second transformation. Is there some intuitive way to think about this? You stated that you're not reflecting first, and that you first take the counterclockwise rotation and THEN reflect, but doesn't the problem state you should do it the other way around? Thanks in advance!

Comment: At no point I wrote that I first take the counterclockwise rotation and then the reflection. Take a look at my answer. I computed the matrix $R$ corresponding to the reflection, I computed the matrix $O$ corresponding to the counterclockwise rotation and then I wrote that the answer is $O.R$. By this order. The matrix $R$ is on the right since it is the **first** operation and the matrix $R$ is on the left since it is the **second** operation. The operations are written from the right to the left.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks a ton again!!